# Python: use presetup figure and layout to use with multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to setup a figure template and use it for multiple plots.

A placeholder function in the figure setup would allow to slot in the actual plot line (ax.plot()) there.

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
class TemplatePlots: 
  def __init__(self, x, y): 
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.Template(x,y)

  def Template (self, ax_label, ay_label, title=None): 
    #set up the figure
    fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(1, sharex=True, figsize=(14,7))
    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel(ax_label, fontsize=14, color='red')
    ax.set_ylabel(ay_label, fontsize=14, color='blue')
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0) , useMathText=True)

    #the actual plot 
    self.linehere    #<-- PLACEHOLDER FOR AX.PLOT
    plt.show()


  #the actual plot function     
  def linehere(self):
    return ax.plot(self.x,self.y)


x=np.arange(0,10,1)
y=x**2

temp=TemplatePlots(x, y)
```

My code isn't working, the line isn't being plotted,

My output: 
[image: Output plot empty]

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: How do I place the ax.plot back in the code? the way I did it doesn't work

Comment: You need to store ax in a variable like `self.ax` to use it in a different method. Also you need to *call* the function (you forgot the `()`).

Comment: thanks, it worked. Is this the normal way of doing it or is there a more used way of setting up a figure to use multiple times ?